# Getting a "Failed to invoke the service" while trying to invoke a wcf service

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I am trying to host a Wcf Service on the IIS, but am unable to do so. I have the service inside a website in IIS added as an application and am also able to get the wsdl for the service. But when trying to hit the service through the WcfTestClient, I get the following error -

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

I have gone through the steps to host a wcf service on the IIS. Not sure what I am missing or doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is error in WCF.

Try putting 
try and catch
or 
make a empty method to return Hello World